# iterator segmentation fault c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, segmentation-fault

I wrote a simple algorithm to display the nth prime. Simply put, it uses a vector of found primes to check if the next number is prime as well; if it is, it pushes it into the vector and repeats until the nth prime is found.

Unfortunately, I am getting a segmentation fault in the for loop nested in the while loop and I have no idea why. More specifically, the error occurs in the header of the for loop; I added a `cerr << "Check " << z++ << endl;` to the body of the for loop (and one before it altogether) to see where it occurred so I believe the error is related to the iterators.

The program is very small and I don't mind sharing it (if you have a use for it have at it) so here's the whole thing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        cerr << "USAGE: nthPrime n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    vector< unsigned > primes;
    vector< unsigned >::iterator it;
    bool isPrime;
    char *sffx = ( char ) 0;
    unsigned n = atoi( argv[ 1 ] ),
             x = 3,
             max;

    primes.push_back( 2 );

    while( primes.size() != n )
    {
        isPrime = true;
        max = ( unsigned )sqrt( x );

        for( it = primes.begin(); *it <= max; ++it )
            if( !( x % *it ) ) isPrime = false;

        if( isPrime ) primes.push_back( x );
        x += 2;
    }

    if( n == 1 ) strcpy( sffx, "st" );
    else if( n == 2 ) strcpy( sffx, "nd" );
    else if( n == 3 ) strcpy( sffx, "rd" );
    else strcpy( sffx, "th" );

    cout << "The " << n << sffx << " prime is " << primes.back() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the makefile too for convienience:

```
CCFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11

nthPrime: nthPrime.o
    g++ $(CCFLAGS) -o nthPrime nthPrime.o

nthPrime.o: nthPrime.cpp
    g++ $(CCFLAGS) -c nthPrime.cpp

clean:
    -rm *.o nthPrime
```

I have neglected to add any comments as I just wrote it an hour ago so please let me know if you would like me to.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have tried adding `&& it != primes.end()` to the for loop but it shouldn't be required due to the properties of the algorithm and it didn't help anyway.

Comment: If you only wrote it an hour ago, you couldn't have done that much debugging. What debugging have you done? Have you looked up what causes a segfault?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of dereferencing a null pointer. Specifically, `sffx` is the null pointer, and `strcpy( sffx, "whatever")` attempts to write through it.

Comment: your while loop should probably be < instead of !=... if I pass in 0 this is an infinite loop.  did you try `it != primes.end() && *it <= max`  because the other way around you are still dereferencing an iterator to memory you don't own and that will cause a segfault.

Comment: Igor - is that an issue though? I'm not certain what that all means :P

Comment: Eddge - yes I tried `&& it != primes.end;`. Good point about n=0 though, thanks.

Comment: @xYouman the memory at your char pointer is null, doing a strcpy on null will attempt to write to that address which you do not have permission to write to, also causes a segfault.  So even if you get passed your segfault in your nested for loop, you will get a segfault there.

Comment: @xYouman `*it <= max && it != primes.end()` is not the same as `it != primes.end() && *it <= max` in the first instance you are still dereferencing an iterator you don't own before you are checking it.  The second example you are checking it before you attempt to dereference it, the left hand side has to be true for the right hand side will be attempted.

Comment: Oh wow your right! Thanks I'll try that immediately.

Comment: That was't it. It was the `char *sffx = ( char ) 0;` line that caused the seg fault. But thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues I can see:

1) using argv without checking

```
unsigned n = atoi( argv[ 1 ] ),
             x = 3,
             max;
```

2) This:

```
char *sffx = ( char ) 0;
```

Does not allocate space for this:

```
if( n == 1 ) strcpy( sffx, "st" );
else if( n == 2 ) strcpy( sffx, "nd" );
else if( n == 3 ) strcpy( sffx, "rd" );
else strcpy( sffx, "th" );
```

Comment: Hmm really? `char *sffx = ( char ) 0;` just initializes the `*char` as empty so I don't get an error. What could go wrong by doing that?

Comment: you need to allocate space for the string you are copying: char *sffx = new char[3];

Comment: Oh ok cool thanks. should I initialize it like that or call that later when i need to?

Comment: Wooow this was the issue! Thank you so much! Could you further explain why that caused a segmentation fault in a for loop that didn't use the `char*`?

Comment: @xYouman What makes you believe it caused the problem inside the loop, and not outside where you actually use `sffx`?

Comment: because I added `cerr` tags in all over the place and that's where it failed

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you everyone for getting back to me so quickly! I thought I'd be waiting all day! The issue turned out to be the line `char *sffx = ( char ) 0;`. Changing it to `char *sffx = new char[ 3 ];` fixed everything.

For anyone who may end up having a similar issue or just wants the program for whatever reason, here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    vector< unsigned > primes;
    vector< unsigned >::iterator it;
    bool isPrime;
    char *sffx = new char[ 3 ];
    unsigned n = atoi( argv[ 1 ] ),
             x = 3,
             max;

    if( argc != 2 || n < 1)
    {
        cerr << "USAGE: nthPrime n>0" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    primes.push_back( 2 );

    while( primes.size() < n )
    {
        isPrime = true;
        max = ( unsigned )sqrt( x );

        for( it = primes.begin(); *it <= max; ++it )
            if( !( x % *it ) ) isPrime = false;

        if( isPrime ) primes.push_back( x );
        x += 2;
    }

    if( n % 10 == 1 && n % 100 != 11 ) strcpy( sffx, "st" );
    else if( n % 10 == 2 && n % 100 != 12 ) strcpy( sffx, "nd" );
    else if( n % 10 == 3 && n % 100 != 13 ) strcpy( sffx, "rd" );
    else strcpy( sffx, "th" );

    cout << "The " << n << sffx << " prime is " << primes.back() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Enjoy and thank you all again!

P.S. the 86626th prime is a cool one I just ran into randomly to test the program at a high value; check it out!

Comment: For anyone who may end up having a similar issue: use std::string!

Comment: haha good point. I thought I would just avoid that since it was gonna be a simple  use. Oh how I was wrong